# Does Xcode have resolve imports functionality?

Tags: xcode, xcode-template

In Eclipse, I rarely have to manually import a file due to its ability to automatically resolve imports using a keyboard shortcut. Is this available in Xcode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto import for Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102013/auto-import-for-xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that mean automatically add the correct #import lines?

Nope.

On the other hand, Cocoa code tends to just pull in the world.  As far as system headers, it's pretty normal to only need <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>, which is already in the template Xcode use for a new file.  You can use a prefix header in your project to cover your own headers.

Comment: But note that with a prefix header you can run into the issue I've got - one little change in one file and Xcode needs to rebuild everything from scratch. At the extreme of this, you've got a build which takes minutes to complete (my current status!)