# Auto import for Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, auto-import

Is it possible for Xcode to auto import the frameworks and class headers automatically?

What happens is that every time I build, I will encounter errors due to missing import. I know how to fix, but I felt Xcode can be more intelligent by perhaps giving me an option to "Auto fix imports".

Comment: Is this real? I cannot believe I cannot auto import a class that I have already defined!

Comment: Can I ask you to review the answers once again and check if one of them satisfies your question?

Comment: None, there is no possible answer because I think Xcode doesn't support this.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment it's not possible to do that. I suppose what you want is something like Eclipse's auto-import, i.e. when you first use a class in code, it auto-imports the package.

You should open a bug report [here](http://bugreporter.apple.com) to let the Apple people know about it.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want. A feature, not bug.

Comment: Yeah, coming from eclipse where command completion of a class adds the "import" is great.  I wish they had it.  Sometimes I wonder if it's worth trying Jetbrains AppCode

Comment: Used AppCode for a while, now I'm back to Xcode. AppCode is great at editing the code, however it feels alien on the Mac. Plus debugging with it is a pain. Also, for Core Data and xib editing you need Xcode anyway, so ...

Comment: Yeah, that's about what I was guessing.  Thanks for the feedback about it.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is old, but it is good to know that @import was added to LLVM with XCode 5. It gives you features that you wanted. You can find more [here](http://stoneofarc.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/introduction-to-objective-c-modules/) and [here](http://jeremywsherman.com/blog/2012/02/29/whats-this-about-at-import/)

Answer (score 3):

You can import a class header into all files automatically by adding it in the .pch file. You will still need to add the frameworks manually though.

Comment: I edited my question, because what I seeking for is to auto fix build errors due to missing imports. I don't think adding all headers to .pch is a good solution.

Comment: It's a very bad advice. Adding a lot of imports to pch will lead to slow and often recompiles in case of changes in those headers.

Answer (score 2):

AppCode has the auto import feature.  In my opinion it's not an Xcode replacement, but a welcome addition.  It has some killer features like multi caret editing, refactoring that actually works, auto import, tabs that don't drive me nuts, structured code view, etc.  Give it a try, you owe it to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you install Alcatraz (package manager for xcode) then you can search for "Auto Importer" and you should be good.

Comment: Note that a search for "Auto importer" is now empty. The plugin is called "Auto-importer".